# Flutter how to make Text Form Field with floating label intro container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter how to make Text Form Field with floatin label intro container?

I try make text field like this, but i don't centered my label if input without focus.

[image: I try make text field like this]

How can i fix it?

Bellow my code. [And my code see here](https://www.dartpad.dev/?id=998f77d3b5de78c79ed64e7ddbfbe836&null_safety=true)

```
class CustomInput extends StatefulWidget {
    final bool enabled;
    final bool readOnly;
    final double? width;
    final double? borderRadius;
    final bool autofocus;
    final int? maxLines;
    final int? maxLength;
    final bool obscureText;
    final String? hintText;
    final String? labelText;
    final String? errorText;
    final String? helperText;
    final String? counterText;
    final String? initialValue;
    final FocusNode? focusNode;
    final void Function()? onTap;
    final EdgeInsetsGeometry? margin;
    final TextInputType? keyboardType;
    final Function(String)? onChanged;
    final Widget? suffixIcon, prefixIcon;
    final TextInputAction? textInputAction;
    final TextEditingController? controller;
    final String? Function(String?)? validator;
    final Iterable<String>? autofillHints;
    final String? Function(String?)? onFieldSubmitted;
    final BoxConstraints? suffixIconConstraints;

    CustomInput({
        Key? key,
        this.controller,
        this.labelText,
        this.maxLength,
        this.focusNode,
        this.enabled = true,
        this.onChanged,
        this.textInputAction,
        this.keyboardType,
        this.onFieldSubmitted,
        this.validator,
        this.hintText,
        this.errorText,
        this.margin,
        this.obscureText = false,
        this.suffixIcon,
        this.autofillHints,
        this.helperText = '',
        this.prefixIcon,
        this.initialValue,
        this.onTap,
        this.readOnly = false,
        this.autofocus = false,
        this.maxLines = 1,
        this.suffixIconConstraints,
        this.width,
        this.counterText,
        this.borderRadius,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
        _CustomInputState createState() => _CustomInputState();
    }

class _CustomInputState extends State<CustomInput> {
    final _key = GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        OutlineInputBorder outlineInputBorder = OutlineInputBorder(
            gapPadding: 0,
            // borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius ??),
        );

        return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
                Container(
                width: widget.width,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                // margin: widget.margin,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius ?? 8),
                    color: !widget.enabled
                        ? Theme.of(context).disabledColor
                        : Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: !widget.enabled
                        ? Theme.of(context).disabledColor
                        : Theme.of(context).dividerColor,
                    ),
                ),
                child: TextFormField(
                    key: _key,
                    onTap: widget.onTap,
                    enabled: widget.enabled,
                    readOnly: widget.readOnly,
                    maxLines: widget.maxLines,
                    onChanged: widget.onChanged,
                    autofocus: widget.autofocus,
                    maxLength: widget.maxLength,
                    focusNode: widget.focusNode,
                    validator: widget.validator,
                    controller: widget.controller,
                    obscureText: widget.obscureText,
                    initialValue: widget.initialValue,
                    keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
                    autofillHints: widget.autofillHints,
                    textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
                    onFieldSubmitted: widget.onFieldSubmitted,
                    cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    isCollapsed: true,
                    // Theme config
                    // alignLabelWithHint: true,
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    height: 3.8,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    // color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                    ),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 28,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 10,
                    ),
                    fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                    border: outlineInputBorder,
                    focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                    enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                    disabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius ?? 8),
                    ),
                    errorStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    height: 0.56,
                    ),

                    // Custom input config
                    filled: !widget.enabled,
                    hintText: widget.hintText,
                    labelText: widget.labelText,
                    errorText: widget.errorText,
                    // helperText: 'widget.helperText',
                    suffixIcon: widget.suffixIcon,
                    prefixIcon: widget.prefixIcon,
                    // helperStyle: TextStyle(height: 0.55),
                    helperStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                    counterText: widget.counterText ?? '',
                    suffixIconConstraints: widget.suffixIconConstraints,
                ),
            ),
            ),
            if (widget.helperText != null)
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 4),
                    child: Text(
                        widget.helperText!,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        );
    }
}
```

The next line does not carry any semantic load, it is leash so that there are no errors when sending the post.The next line does not carry any semantic load, it is leash so that there are no errors when sending the post.

Comment: I found something in the `input_decorator.dart` from the flutter sdk:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1cUR.png
Maybe we can copy the content and manipulate it to our needs, but I think this is a very bad practice.
I'd love to see more flexiblity on that InputDecoration.

Answer (score 1):

You should try below code :

Create Controller

```
final TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
```

Create TextFormFiled Widget:

```
TextFormField(
      controller: username,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Username',
        hintText: 'Enter Username',
       
      ),
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
    ),
```

then execute above code
your screen look like this[image]

Try below code I think this is help you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    final TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextFormField(
      controller: username,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Username',
        hintText: 'Enter Username',
       
      ),
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
    ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sory bro, but U don't undestend me. I try make Input like screenshot example. I try centered title when my input without focus.

Comment: Hey Bro can you test above code? please check my updated answer with image

Comment: What was the problem Brother

Comment: My label dont up. If input without focus. See my screenshot.

Comment: Can you share your TextField Code

Comment: I think you try my above code with other Textfield insted of your textfield

Comment: This [my code ](https://www.dartpad.dev/?id=998f77d3b5de78c79ed64e7ddbfbe836&null_safety=true)

Comment: Ok I will check

Comment: I have gone your code I think It is working correct but I dont understand why noy up the message BTW I have  update my answer try to updated code is **MyApp** class

Comment: This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CommonTextFieldWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TextEditingController? controller;
  final String? hintText;
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final bool? readOnly;
  final bool? obscureText;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final int? errorMaxLines;
  final bool? autoFocus;
  final bool? enableSuffixIconVisibility;
  final bool? isDropDown;
  final Function? callBack;
  CommonTextFieldWidget(
      {Key? key,
      this.callBack,
      this.controller,
      this.hintText,
      this.validator,
      this.keyboardType,
      this.readOnly,
      this.onTap,
      this.obscureText,
      this.errorMaxLines,
      this.autoFocus,
      this.enableSuffixIconVisibility,
      this.isDropDown})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CommonTextFieldWidgetState createState() => _CommonTextFieldWidgetState();
}

class _CommonTextFieldWidgetState extends State<CommonTextFieldWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
      child: TextFormField(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          controller: widget.controller,
          readOnly: widget.readOnly!,
          autofocus: widget.autoFocus!,
          obscureText: widget.obscureText!,
          onTap: widget.onTap,
          cursorColor: Colors.white,
          keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              errorMaxLines: widget.errorMaxLines,
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
              labelText: widget.hintText,
              labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
              hintText: widget.hintText,
              hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
              border: InputBorder.none),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            widget.callBack!(newValue ?? "");
          },
          validator: widget.validator),
    );
  }
}
```